# No Windows Store apps (anymore) in Visual Studio 2013 Preview

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I have downloaded and installed (on a new PC) Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Preview and selected Windows Store apps as one of the things to install during setup.

Everything else is there; just doesn't seem to have any support for Windows Store apps in this installation. Is there anywhere I can download it manually. I've tried "modifying" the installation to re-install WinStore app support but it didn't install it:

[image]

Comment: Also, after installation, the "Windows App Cert Kit" tile was added to the Start screen - but I am still unable to create new Windows Store app projects in VS 2013.

Comment: this sounds like something to feed back via "connect"...?

Comment: @MarcGravell, thank you; I will go there now and see if the issue has already been raised over there.

Comment: I cannot find anything on Connect about this so I am going to leave feedback. But I am wondering if there is a workaround like manually downloading files for Windows Store apps and installing them?

Comment: Oh FFS. I just found http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/791089/vs-2013-ultimate-preview-no-template-for-windows-store-apps - they say that VS 2013 cannot create Store apps on Windows 8?!?!?! WTF. I need to install Windows 8.1. I already had that and the changes they made were absolute garbage. Great.

Comment: •Windows Store app development in Visual Studio is supported only on Windows 8.1 Preview and Windows 8. That's what the MSDN page says. So VS 2013 Ultimate Preview should be working on Windows 8. Anybody know how to get around this?

Comment: Windows Store app development is available on Windows 8, but with Visual Studio 2012. If you'd like to use VS2013 you have to install Windows 8.1

Comment: it is a **technology preview**; there's no point using that level of punctuation

Comment: If your creating a new project then it targets 8.1 only. If you open an existing 8.0 project then you can open and edit it...or retarget it to 8.1. http://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/you-can-target-only-windows-81-with-vs2013/  and ... http://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/visual-studio-2013-support-for-targeting-windows-8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your creating a new project then it targets 8.1 only.

If you open an existing 8.0 project then you can open and edit it...or re-target it to 8.1.

So the implication is IF you are on Windows 8, you *might* be ok in loading existing Windows Store App 8.0 projects...you just won't be able to create new ones...as they target 8.1.

See these references:

- http://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/you-can-target-only-windows-81-with-vs2013/
- http://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/visual-studio-2013-support-for-targeting-windows-8/

Answer (score 1):

Windows Store apps of visual studio are not supported in windows 7 machine or older version of windows. it is only compatible with windows Windows 8 and never version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install windows 8.1 because windows 8 does not provide you the facility for making windows app store in preview of the visual studio.